# Docker JAVA 11 - Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.Invalid -Xlog option

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, docker, garbage-collection

i'm running a spring-boot application in a docker container (base-image adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot) and using docker-compose to start up.

To enable GC-Log, I'v added the following argument in the entrypoint:

```
exec java -server -Xlog:gc=debug:file=/gclog/gc.log:pid,time,level,uptime:filecount=5,filesize=1M ...
```

It works on my machine (mac os) and I can use the application. But when I deploy the container from the same image in the remote machine (linux) I get the following exception when starting up the container:

```
| Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc=debug:file=/gclog/gc.log:pid,time,level,uptime:filecount=5,filesize=1M', see error log for details.
| Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
| Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
| [0.001s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/gclog/gc.log': No such file or directory
| [0.002s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=/gclog/gc.log' using options 'filecount=5,filesize=1M' failed.
```

I'v tried different paths in "file=..." and still not works.

ps: i'm using the same docker version and i have to mounted volume to the container

Comment: well, _obviously_  something _is_ different. just start the application without that log and see if there is such a directory tree and file.

Comment: without enabling gc-log the directory "/gclog" does not exists, it should be created automatically by the JVM.
The error is: No such file or directory. 
It looks like the JVM is looking for the file and not writing a new one.

Comment: @jihedzaoueli: it seems like the directory should exist and only the file will be created. Why do you think that the VM should create the directory as well?

Comment: Because on my machine the directory was automatically created :(

Comment: So i've solved by creating the directory before starting the JVM. It also work if i only mount the "/gclog" volume  with the host (in docker-compose)
Thank you.

Comment: On your machine the directory was not created, it probably existed already. The VM creates the file ( via `fopen` ), but never creates the directories.

Comment: yes that was the problem, Thank you. it works on my machine because I already mounted the directory "/gclog" with the host in docker-compose file